# How to apply abilities to a non-restful controller in cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I'm new to rails and for the life of me I don't "get" cancan.

I've read [this tutorial](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Non-RESTful-Controllers) but can't figure out how to apply instructions to my situation.

In the cancan wiki there is:

- an AdminController
- a roll_logs action

In the ability class is says:

```
can :roll, :logs if user.admin?
```

I don't get what the :roll and :logs symbols have to do with the controller and the action?

All I want to do is say, if a user is an admin, give them access to the AdminController actions, otherwise don't, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

The statement

```
can :roll, :logs if user.admmin?
```

means that when calling `authorize! :roll, :logs` an unauthorized exception gets thrown if the user isn't an admin.

So it doesn't have anything to do with a controller or an action, untill you make it so.

If you have a logs_controller for example with an action roll you could do something like this.

```
class LogsController < ApplicationController

  def roll
    authorize! :roll, :logs

    # Rest of the roll functionality.
  end
```

So in your example, you want to give users who are admin permission to access all admin controller actions.

You can achieve this like this.

**ability.rb**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can(:manage, :admin) if user.admin?
  end
end
```

**admin_controller.rb**

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController

 authorize_resource :class => false

 def foo
 end

 def bar
 end

end
```

This will make sure that only admins can access the foo and bar actions of the admin_controller.

The `:class => false` statement means that you are not authorizing a resource, which is what we want since you are not for example authorizing a certain post or comment. You are just authorizing actions on a controller.

Comment: +1 Thanks so much Arjan, you're explanation is super clear! I wish it was that clear in the documentation! Thanks again, much appreciated.